# Can't install rubygems

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

Hi I would appreciate some help installing rubygems. This is what happens when I try. "ruby-full" has already been installed. How do I fix this? What is the issue?

```
$ sudo apt-get install rubygems 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package rubygems is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  ruby

E: Package 'rubygems' has no installation candidate
```

I am running Ubuntu Studio 14.04. Ruby version installed: 1:1.9.3.4. Please let me know if there are any other additional details that could help solve this issue.

Comment: The package name is actually `rubygems1.9.1` (as seen in http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=rubygem&searchon=names&suite=trusty&section=all). It is advisable to RVM or other version manager intsead.

Answer (score 1):

Rubygems is part of Ruby 1.9 itself. Thus, there is no need to install it seperately, you already have it installed. As such, the "old" rubygems package is now either a virtual package or is simply also provided by the ruby package (or more specifically by the `ruby1.9.1` package in Trusty.

tl;dr of this is: if you have `ruby1.9.1` installed, you already have rubygems installed and don't need any additional packages.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using Rbenv instead of RVM https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install rubygems-integration
```